# How to get array dimension in 1 direction in awk multidimension array

Tags: arrays, awk

Is there any way to get only one dimension length in `awk` array like in php

look at this simple example

```
     awk 'BEGIN{
                   a[1,1]=1;
                   a[1,2]=2;
                   a[2,1]=3;
                   a[2,3]=2;
                   print length(a)
               }'
```

Here length of array is 4 which includes each field as an entity, my interest is to get how many rows are there in array, in real code of mine I have n number of fields setting array like this

```
             for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)A[FNR,i]=$i
```

problem is fields are not fixed in my file, sometimes fields are varying in each row, so I cannot calculate even like this `length(array)/NF`

Is there any solution ?

Comment: Won't the result be equal to `FNR` in the `END` block? Or are you opening multiple files?

Comment: You can store `NF` as part of your key, `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) A[FNR,i,NF]=$i}...` and if you need to retrieve it later on, just split on `SUBSEP` and test the 3rd element of the key which will be number of fields.

Comment: @jaypal: no need to add extra index to array since he/she wants only number of row...

Answer (score 2):

Use GNU awk since it has true mufti-dimensional arrays:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    a[1][1]=1;
    a[1][2]=2;
    a[1][3]=3;
    a[2][1]=4;
    a[2][2]=5;
    print length(a)
    print length(a[1])
    print length(a[2])
}'
2
3
2
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by counting unique index in array, try something like this

```
           awk '
               function _get_rowlength(Arr,fnumber, i,t,c){

                for(i in Arr){ 
                               split(i,sep,SUBSEP)
                               if(!(sep[fnumber] in t))
                               {
                                   c++
                                   t[sep[fnumber]]
                               }
                             }
                    return c;
               }

               BEGIN{
                              a[1,1]=1;
                              a[1,2]=2;
                              a[2,1]=3;
                              a[2,3]=2;

                              print _get_rowlength(a,1)
                     }'
```

**Resulting**

```
             $ ./tester
             2
```

If you want to try this on a `Solaris/SunOS` system, change `awk` to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` , `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk`